# Java Selenium TestNG: problems with framework (a project) when used by another project

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, testng, project

I created a framework with Selenium and TestNg in Java, it is a Maven project.
I have another project (Test project) that should use the framework to run.
Test project has a TesNG xml file where i write the class of the framework to run.

The framework class runs, however it doesn't do anything.
Variables won't be set, `System.out.println("data");` for example will not print anything.

It's like a ghost framework.

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="listeners.TestNGListeners"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <parameter name="class"
            value="Google" />
        <parameter name="resource" value="src/main/resources/excel/Google.xlsx" />
        <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />
        <classes>
            <class name="utils.ExcelDataProvider" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

`ExcelDataProvider` is the class belonging to the framework that starts.
Parameter belong to Test project.

Do you know why i have this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it. I had to insert the framework as a dependency in the POM file (test project) instead of adding it in the Build path.

Still i have some problems, like `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

It can't find the test project class `<parameter name="class"value="Google" />`